# DataTables Align Text in Column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables in my app and it works great. To center the text, I'm using:

```
{ className: 'dt-center', targets: '_all' },
```

However, for the last column, I want to align the text left instead of center, but the following is having no effect:

```
{ targets: [ 12 ], className: 'dt-left' }
```

Here is my complete code:

```
$('#audits-datatable').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { width: '70px', targets: [ 0, 1, 11 ] },
        { width: '125px', targets: [ 8 ] },
        { width: '600px', targets: [ 12 ] },
        { className: 'dt-center', targets: '_all' },
        { targets: [ 12 ], className: 'dt-left' }
    ],
});
```

Why is "dt-left" not overriding "dt-center" in column 12? It still shows up aligned centered instead of left.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution. I'll post it here in hopes of helping someone. The key was reversing lines 6 and 7; however, it only worked for the table body, not the table header. For the table header, I needed to add className: 'dt-head-left'.

Final code that worked for me:

```
$('#audits-datatable').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
        { width: '70px', targets: [ 0, 1, 11 ] },
        { width: '125px', targets: [ 8 ] },
        { width: '600px', targets: [ 12 ] },
        { targets: [ 12 ], width: '650px', className: 'dt-left', className: 'dt-head-left' },
        { targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center' }
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. But this is what I found in my investigation. From my finding, the solution is simple but the reason behind the problem is important to know.

I don't know in your 12th column, what kind of value you are using.
I'm assuming, it would either `date` or `numeric` value.
Let's assume, our column holds a date value.

If so, when we initially load the table, the library adds an additional class `dt-type-date` to the cell,

```
<td class="dt-type-date">2024-03-06 15:42:33</td>
```

Now, when we assign additional configuration to our datatable object like this,

```
columnDefs: [
  {
     targets: '_all',
     className: 'dt-left'
  }
],
```

the library adds the `.dt-left` class to the cell

```
<td class="dt-type-date dt-left">2024-03-06 15:42:33</td>
```

But the `dt-type-date` class overrides the css from `.dt-left` or `.dt-right`.

If we look at these class, they all have the same css property which is `text-align` and if we look at the css file `datatables.min.css` file, the `.dt-type-date` class is defined after the
`.dt-left` and `.dt-right`. This is why the `.dt-left` configuration is not working.

**Solution:**

I had to explicitly tell, `.dt-head-left` and `.dt-body-left` to the specific datatable configuration object. And it works.

In your case, it'd be like I guess,

```
{ targets: [ 12 ], className: 'dt-head-left dt-body-left' }
```

I hope that solves the problem.